# Working on a small exercise that deals with converting integers to months

Tags: python

Working on a small script that converts integers to month names. The problem i'm currently having is that i'm currently trying to get familiar with dictionaries, and have stored the integer 1 with the value of "January". When I use the get method on this dict, it doesn't print the value, but just restarts the loop. Here is the code:

```
months = {1: "January"}
while True:
    try:
        month_number_input = input("Enter a month:")
        if month_number_input.isalpha():
            raise ValueError("Please enter a number")
        elif month_number_input == 1:
            print(months.get(1))
    except ValueError as VE:
        print(VE)
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code like

```
    elif int(month_number_input) == 1:
```

"month_number_input" is not int type so you have to do typecasting

Answer (score 0):

month_number_input is of string type. so change the condition as

```
 elif month_number_input =='1':
```

or just typecast the month_number_input to integer type.

```
elif int(month_number_input) == 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer the result from input is a string ("1") and not an integer (1). In Python "1" and 1 cannot be meaningfully compared. To workaround this you should either use string keys in your dictionary or convert the input to an integer using the `int()` function.

My personal recommendation would be to just use string keys in your dictionary and not use conditional statements to decide what to print. Do something like:

```
months = {"1": "Jan", "2": "Feb", ...}
```

Then instead of using if statements just do:

```
month_number_input = input("Enter a month:")
print("Month is", months.get(month_number_input, "Invalid number"))
```

Comment: A benefit of dong things this way is that you also no longer need to catch a ValueError to detect bad input, which further collapses what you've written.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you want your script to converts **integers** to month names, you can get your input as an integer:

```
int(input("Enter a month:"))
```

Code would be:

```
months = {1: "January",2: "February",3: "March"}
while True:
    try:
        month_number_input = int(input("Enter a month:"))   
        print(months.get(month_number_input))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        break
```

I add a break at the very end, otherwise you will get an infinite loop.